# Show an alert to a user only once

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, web, popup

I wish to show users of my website a pop-up alert on their first visit, but not on subsequent visits.

Since I only have basic HTML and scripting knowledge, please explain how I can i implement this using cookies or other browser features.

You can see the current state of my website at http://www.hdfbcover.com/

Comment: Yes, use cookies, and be sure to set long expiration time.

Comment: This link might be useful for you. 
http://www.spiceupyourblog.com/2012/01/one-time-facebook-pop-up-like-box-for.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example using cookies, you could also do something similar with localStorage rather than the cookie.

```
// Check If Cookie exists and if it doesn't exists
if( $.cookie('example') == null ) {
    // Create cookie
    $.cookie( 'example', '1',  { expires: 7, path: '/' } );
    // Display popup
    // Your code here...
}
```

Reference:

- [jQuery $.cookie](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie)
- [HTML5 localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

Comment: Post all of the relevant code. That isn't something you can just slap in. You would need to change it to fit your existing code.

Answer (score 1):

If you have registered users, you should decide on saving data locally or on the server:

**On server**

If you have a user database, you could store and set a flag (boolean value) indicating whether the user has seen the message. This could easily be made generic enough to show different kinds of messages and show them at different times. And advantage here is that you know whether the user has seen the message regardless of where he is connected from.

**Locally**

You could use local storage, for instance HTML5's localStorage or a [jQuerys cookie plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/Cookie). There you would save flags of whether the user has seen the message. Obviously here you dont know whether the user has seen the message if he is connected from a new computer.

Comment: My website : http://goo.gl/hzZgU   . I don't use registered users and other High level codes. Simple HTML code.